# Moved some code to a new class why im getting cannot convert error on the AnimatedPictureBox[] pbs?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in Form1:

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   PbsWheel pbsw = new PbsWheel(pbs, pb, e.Delta, pb.AnimateRate, label2);
}
```

In the bottom of form1 i have this class:

```
public class AnimatedPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    List<string> imageFilenames;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    public AnimatedPictureBox()
    {
        AnimateRate = 100; //It's up to you, the smaller, the faster.
        t.Tick += Tick_Animate;
    }
    public int AnimateRate
    {
        get { return t.Interval; }
        set { t.Interval = value; }
    }
    public void Animate(List<string> imageFilenames)
    {
        this.imageFilenames = imageFilenames;
        t.Start();
    }
    public void StopAnimate()
    {
        t.Stop();
        i = 0;
    }
    int i;
    private void Tick_Animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageFilenames == null) return;
        Load(imageFilenames[i]);
        i = (i + 1) % imageFilenames.Count;
    }
}
```

Now in the new class i have the same class AnimatedPcitureBox and also this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherMaps
{
    class PbsWheel
    {
        public PbsWheel(AnimatedPictureBox[] pbs, AnimatedPictureBox pb, int delta, int speed,Label label2)
        {
            //if (leave == true)
            //{
            for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {

                if (delta > 0)
                {
                    if (speed < 5000)
                    {
                        if (speed < 1000)
                        {
                            speed += 100;
                            label2.Text = (speed / (double)1000).ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            speed += 1000;
                            label2.Text = (speed / 1000).ToString();
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (speed > 1000)
                    {
                        speed -= 1000;
                        label2.Text = (speed / 1000).ToString();
                    }

                    else

                    if (speed <= 1000 && speed > 100)
                    {
                        speed -= 100;
                        label2.Text = (speed / (double)1000).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }


            //}        
        }

        public class AnimatedPictureBox : PictureBox
        {
            List<string> imageFilenames;
            Timer t = new Timer();
            public AnimatedPictureBox()
            {
                AnimateRate = 100; //It's up to you, the smaller, the faster.
                t.Tick += Tick_Animate;
            }
            public int AnimateRate
            {
                get { return t.Interval; }
                set { t.Interval = value; }
            }
            public void Animate(List<string> imageFilenames)
            {
                this.imageFilenames = imageFilenames;
                t.Start();
            }
            public void StopAnimate()
            {
                t.Stop();
                i = 0;
            }
            int i;
            private void Tick_Animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (imageFilenames == null) return;
                Load(imageFilenames[i]);
                i = (i + 1) % imageFilenames.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when im doing in Form1 this line:

```
PbsWheel pbsw = new PbsWheel(pbs, pb, e.Delta, pb.AnimateRate, label2);
```

Im getting 3 errors on pbs and pb. And pbs and pb are AnimatedPictureBox type.

> Error  11  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'WeatherMaps.Form1.AnimatedPictureBox[]' to 'WeatherMaps.PbsWheel.AnimatedPictureBox[]'
>
> Error  12  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'WeatherMaps.Form1.AnimatedPictureBox' to 'WeatherMaps.PbsWheel.AnimatedPictureBox'
>
> Error  10  The best overloaded method match for 'WeatherMaps.PbsWheel.PbsWheel(WeatherMaps.PbsWheel.AnimatedPictureBox[], WeatherMaps.PbsWheel.AnimatedPictureBox, int, int, System.Windows.Forms.Label)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have 2 separate classes for `AnimatedPictureBox` as you have them as internal classes inside `Form1` and `WeatherMaps`. It doesn't matter that the code and name is the same - the classes are different.

It will be better for you to move it to a new class that is not sitting inside any other class. Preferably you can move it to its own file too.

Comment: Ok moved it to a new class its working now. But now the wheel is not doing anything. The new class pbswheel is getting Delta. In form1 in the form1 mouse wheel event i did: PbsWheel pbsw = new PbsWheel(pbs, pb, e.Delta, pb.AnimateRate, label2); but for some reason when i roll/move the mouse wheel when the program is running its not do anything.

Comment: When you debug, does it call all relevant methods passing the delta?

Comment: Yes i see that e.Delta is passed to delta and the speed also ill check again.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I changed it deleted the speed variable instead changed all the speed variables in the pbswheel class and replaced it with pbs[i].AnimateRate and now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well the error is clear.

there are two classes with the same name in different namespaces.

create a new file an put it there, use it in both form / PbsWeel

Answer (score 0):

Another way on doing it is to create a custom control. By adding the custom control to your `Form1`, the `Form1.Designer` will do the things for you.